# Wix : installation path not taking from dialog,Always install in the default direcory

Tags: wix, installation

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="InetPub" Name="inetpub">
    <Directory Id="wwwroot" Name="wwwroot">
      <Directory Id="InstallDir" Name="AppName">
```

And also Have a dialog to getting the path from the user,but still after installation it goes to wwwroot folder.?

Comment: You need to supply way more info in order to get some help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using   `<UIRef Id="WixUI_Mondo" />`, where you choose custom, you can browse and install to any directory.

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder">
    <Directory Id="CompanyDir" Name="Company">
      <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="IPDev">
```

also make sure you have a line like so before the componenets:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
  <Directory Id="dir_SampleImages_0" Name="SampleImages">
    <Component Id="comp_SAMPLE_IMAGES_0" DiskId="1" KeyPath="yes" Guid="2FCE9C4A-47B7-4473-BF6E-8ED14C5A9AB0">
      <File Name="Aptina1.raw" Id="file_SAMPLE_IMAGES_0" Source="..\Import\SampleImages\Aptina\400lux_DPonblueEdgehor_bigred0005.raw" />
    </Component>
```

If you have any other problems please share your full code